What ways are there, if any, to read/edit a PDF's human-readable format (operators/operands)
It is my understanding that PDFs, or at least some parts of PDFs have a readable text representation, i.e. language. (Not very readable! But readable.) In the process of learning about how PDFs can be processed by APIs I have several times seen something like this:
BT
    /F0 36 Tf
    50 706 Td
    (Hello, World!) Tj
    /F0 12 Tf
    (Hello, Again!) Tj
ET

Sure this is not the height of readability, but for some tasks modifying this sort of text stream is liable to be simpler than coding against an API.
(I don't know whether the entirety of a PDF doc can be represented this way? Obviously images and embedded fonts would have to be encoded into Base64 or similar? But I'm not especially interested in that.)
An API (preferably Java) which facilitates this would be ideal, but a GUI tool would also be handy.
Thanks

You mention both iText and pdfbox in your tags. Both of them allow you to access all the PDF objects and their respective content, in particular to retrieve and set stream contents.

@mkl I couldn't however see any way to get and manipulate the plain text form of the operators/operands as in the example above. Did I miss something?

If you can retrieve the (decrypted and decompressed) steam contents and replace them with new contents, then you can manipulate a plain text form, can't you? Except of course that readable string argument contents are the exception.

@mkl When you said "stream contents" I assume you meant a "stream" of Java objects (such as Operator, COSObject), not of plain text. Are you saying I could operate on a stream of the characters representing operators/operands (including replacing them)? If so could you link to an example? As for readable string objects... in the examples I've looked at including the on posted the strings are readable. But is that not usually the case? Does this depend on the font encoding?

"When you said "stream contents" I assume you meant a "stream" of Java objects (such as Operator, COSObject), not of plain text." - No. in your question you talked about the raw data, so I meant the plain content. I explicitly said "content", though, not "text". "text" gives the impression of a consistent encoding, but in contrast to examples like the one you show you can have a multitude of encodings in such content: The syntax elements (operators, delimiters) are ASCII'ish but the contents of strings can have different encodings.

In iText PdfStream.getBytes gives you a byte[], and PdfStream.setData allows you to set the stream contents to a byte[]. In PDFBox COSStream.createInputStream gives you an InputStream, and COSStream.createOutputStream allows you to write the stream contents.

"in the examples I've looked at including the on posted the strings are readable. But is that not usually the case?" - Indeed, that is only the case for examples (examples usually are simplifications) and outputs of simple PDF generators. "Does this depend on the font encoding?" - Correct.

You might want to take a look at the PdfCanvasProcessor for iText (see here) or the PdfContentStreamEditor for PDFBox (see here). They allow a basic event based editing of content streams.

With PDF4Java library you can inspect and modify the page content stream by extending the PDFPageTransform class. Existing operators can be modified or removed, new operators can be added.
Code sample below shows how to inspect the page content for show text operators (Tj)
public class OperatorInspector extends PDFPageTransform {
    @Override
    protected void transformOperator(PDFContentStreamOperator input, ArrayList<PDFContentStreamOperator> output) {
        switch (input.getType()) {
            case MOVE_TEXT_POSITION: // Td
                PDFMoveTextPositionOperator mtpo = (PDFMoveTextPositionOperator)input;
                System.out.printf("X: %f; Y: %f\r\n", mtpo.getTX(), mtpo.getTY());
                break;
            case SHOW_TEXT: // Tj
                PDFShowTextOperator sto = (PDFShowTextOperator)input;
                System.out.println(sto.getText().getValue());
                sto.setText(new PDFCosString(sto.getText().getValue() + " - Updated text"));
                break;
            case SHOW_TEXT_2: // TJ
                // ...
                break;
            case SHOW_TEXT_3: // '
                // ...
                break;
            case SHOW_TEXT_4: // "
                // ...
                break;
        }

        // Keep the operator by copying it to output
        output.add(input);
    }

    public static void run(String pdfFileName) {
        PDFFixedDocument document = new PDFFixedDocument(pdfFileName);

        PDFPageTransformer pageTransformer = new PDFPageTransformer(document.getPage(0));
        pageTransformer.applyTransform(new OperatorInspector());

        document.save("updated.pdf");
    }
}

You can also use PDFXplorer to inspect and modify the content streams in a GUI application.

Note: I work for the company that develops these products.

The PDF4Java code example does look rather friendlier to use than iText or PDFBox. Though not free, of course! With PDFXplorer can I just edit the text view and immediately see the effect of changes? I think that could be very useful!

@barneypitt PDFXplorer: At this moment you have to save the PDF file after making changes in order to view them in Pages explorer. This bug will be fixed in a future update.

The text replacement in the example looks like it expects an ASCII'ish encoding of the current font.

Yes, the simple example assumes WinAnsi font encoding like in the question. A more complex example requires to handle the Tf operator, store the active font, encode the string based on the font encoding and then create the PDFCosString object from the encoded value.

You can run
cpdf -output-json -output-json-parse-content-streams in.pdf -o out.json
Then edit, then run
cpdf -j out.json -o out.pdf
to get your PDF back.
A page stream might look like this:
2, {
"S": [
  {}, [
  [
  { "F": 1.0 }, { "F": 0.0 }, { "F": 0.0 }, { "F": 1.0 }, { "F": 50.0 }, {
  "F": 770.0 }, "cm" ], [ "BT" ], [ "/F0", { "F": 36.0 }, "Tf" ], [
  "Hello, World!", "Tj" ], [ "ET" ] ]
] } ]

But whether this method is practical for you will very much depend on your input files. If they're all from the same source (i.e produced by the same program) you might to be able to do what you want. But, for example, editing text in arbitrary PDFs is likely to be impossible for any number of reasons.
Best to start with the command line tools, but the Java API is here: https://github.com/coherentgraphics/cpdflib-binary
